# Map Reduce error in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mapreduce

The following is the map-reduce script in python for finding count of particular column.
The input file is as follows:

```
 301838690844557314|#awkwarddate first date at     quiznoes|334910568|gabriellarichh|20130213|awkwarddate|Point|40.456664|-74.265167
 301838679280861185|RT @jimmyfallon: Ended my very first date by saying, "Take it easy." And  then my dad drove me home.  #awkwarddate|618516844|heyitsbrooke456|20130213|awkwarddate|NULL|NULL|NULL
 301838678026768384|RT @jimmyfallon: Hashtag game! Tweet out a funny, weird, or embarrassing story about a date you've been on and tag w/ #awkwarddate. Could be on our show!|116973704|VegasPhotog|20130213|awkwarddate|NULL|NULL|NULL
```

The map reduce script is:
map code is:

```
import sys

def read_input(file):
    for line in file:
        # split the line into words
        yield line.split('|')

def main(separator='|'):
    # input comes from STDIN (standard input)
    data = read_input(sys.stdin)
    for words in data:
        # write the results to STDOUT (standard output);
        # what we output here will be the input for the
        # Reduce step, i.e. the input for reducer.py
        #
        # tab-delimited; the trivial word count is 1
        if len(words)==9:
            for word[5] in words:
                print '%s%s%d' % (word[5], separator, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

reduce code is:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import sys

def read_mapper_output(file, separator='|'):
    for line in file:
        yield line.rstrip().split(separator, 1)

def main(separator='|'):
    # input comes from STDIN (standard input)
    data = read_mapper_output(sys.stdin, separator=separator)
    # groupby groups multiple word-count pairs by word,
    # and creates an iterator that returns consecutive keys and their group:
    #   current_word - string containing a word (the key)
    #   group - iterator yielding all ["&lt;current_word&gt;", "&lt;count&gt;"] items
    for current_word, group in groupby(data, itemgetter(0)):
        try:
            total_count = sum(int(count) for current_word, count in group)
            print "%s%s%d" % (current_word, separator, total_count)
        except ValueError:
            # count was not a number, so silently discard this item
            pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When i run the above script in hadoop i get the following error:

```
failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201302281754_0001_m_000000
```

I want to get the count of column 6(awkwarddate)
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the `hadoop` command that started the job?

Comment: Remove the `[5]` in `for word[5] in words:`

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down a bit further since you want to count column 6 of each line.

```
def to_std_out(line, sep='|'):
    words = line.split(sep)

    print '%s%s%d' % (words[5], sep, 1)
```

Now in your script entry point (represented as the `main()` function in your case), the logic could be:

```
def main(sep='|'):
    # read in stdin line by line, usually you might need an indefinite loop
    # for the sake of simplicity, I'll be using while 1
    while 1:
        lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            to_std_out(line, sep)
```

Hope this is what you're looking for :)

Comment: hadoop command which i used:     bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.0.4.jar -file /home/savitha/Desktop/map.py    -mapper /home/savitha/Desktop/map.py  -file /home/savitha/Desktop/reducer.py   -reducer /home/savitha/Desktop/reducer.py  -input /tweets/testtweets -output /tweets/output

Comment: @ woozyking i tried the above code. The map reduce job is running but stops with the below error:Task attempt_201303010959_0007_m_000000_0 failed to report status for 601 seconds. Killing!

Comment: @savitha is it the exact word "awkwarddate" you want to count, or the column 6 in general?

Comment: @savitha I edited with the further understanding, for mapper.